# Practical limits of Word/VBA apps

Tags: vba, ms-word

The company I work for has an internally developed Word2003/VBA application that's already about 6.5 mb in size and they're looking to add an additional 200+ macros to it, which, I'm assuming, will make it much larger. This seems to me to be a terrible idea, but finding resources to redevelop the tool with VSTO or some other more useful technology will be a challenge.

So here are my questions:

- Is it okay, in a pinch, to have a
  business dependency on a Word
  template with macros that's 10, 20,
  or 30 mb?
- Is there a Microsoft-defined or
  suggested limit (file size, number of
  macros, level of complexity) to how
  far you can/should extend a VBA app
  before it becomes unusable?

In essence, I'd like to know if there is a compelling technical reason to bite the bullet and redevelop this app.

Comment: What's the unit of "200+"? And: 6.5 MB does not say much about the size of the code base contained in that Word2003/VBA application.

Comment: Each macro is a node in a decision tree, so an if-then-else plus the resulting text that gets inserted. As for the 6.5 mb, the Word doc is 60 pages long, no images, so much of the file size is attributable to macros that walk you through the intricacies of a complex medical exclusion on an insurance policy. Still not much more detail, I know, but in the abstract my question is simply this: Is it reasonable to build a relatively important business system using Word2003 and VBA when it will require hundreds of macros and result in a file of 10 mb or more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will give you the limits of Word 2003/VBA: [Operating parameter limitations and specifications in Word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211489). Given the limit is 150 macros, it doesn't look like they will be able to continue to use this to add 200+ macros.

Comment: +1 for reading through Word specifications

Comment: +1 indeed. also note on that link that max file size is 32mb (for text, not including graphics. Not the 50-100mb I had listed in my answer.

Comment: What is their definition of "macro"?  I have templates with more than 150 VBA subs/functions.

Comment: interesting. i wasn't about to write 151 to test this out. my theory here is that a macro is a sub routine, not a function, because i have yet to find in the help files the term *macro* used with a function.

Answer (score 2):

I would look at moving some of those macros to an Add-in. Still VBA, but can be used on multiple files and gets the code away from the data (which is a programming win, generally).

--Edit--
As for scaling and size... I think it's all in the design. If it is thrown together, performance will suffer. The file can handle the overall size, but there are limits to Module size (64k), and procedure size (not well documented, but the IDE will let you know when you've hit it). If you start to approach 30mb of text only then you're going to want to find another solution.

You haven't mentioned security, but since this has to do with medical information it should be said that VBA is not secure. If the code is proprietary, and being offered to outside sources you might want to wrap it up in an .xll and install as an add-in. This might actually offer a faster runtime as well.

Comment: Got it. So do you know of any guidance out there on how far you can scale Word/VBA apps?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. But its seems unlikely there were 200+ macros. Unless they've made every function, or sub a seperate macro, instead of putting them all in the one Macro.

You can write a VBA application within a word macro. But this doesn't sound like it was. Its just a a bunch of macros.

Comment: From his comment on his own post, it sounds like they wrapped a bunch of commands into named functions or sub routines.